# AUCTeX + CDLaTeX pair insertion

Tags: latex, auctex

I think CDLaTeX might be causing problems with this. If I disable `electric-pair-mode` and use AUCteX’s built-in completion, auto-completion of pairs such as `\[\]` works as expected unless I have CDLaTeX mode enabled. It seems having CDLaTeX mode enabled just gives me completions of `([{`, but not `\[`, `\left(`, etc. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `cdlatex-takeover-parenthesis` to `nil` in order to not have cdlatex use it's own parenthesis completion.

This leaves cdlatex's autoexpansion of `lr(` to `\left( \right)` intact but also automatically adds the `\right)` if you type `\left(`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me.Thank you walterh.